# failed when doing JSON Serialization in iOS, but the API is OK when it is accessed via browser

Tags: php, ios, json

I am trying to retrieve data from my own API, if i try to connect to my API using chrome browser, it gives JSON data back like this

> {"id":"52","username":"aasad23","fullname":"aasad
>   laksana","email":"aasad@gmail.com","avatar":"/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Twitter/Avatar/52/avatar.jpg"}

but, when I tried to access the API through my iOS app, it gives an error while doing JSON serialization, it give an error: 
**the data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format**

what does it mean the correct format?

I have checked that the code error in this line

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

Thats why the `catch` error is activated and give that error message.

here is the full code of this task

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in




            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                if error == nil {



                    do {

                        // json containes $returnArray from php
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                        // declare new parseJSON to store json
                        guard let parsedJSON = json else {
                            print("Error while parsing")
                            return
                        }


                        print(parsedJSON)

                        // get id from $returnArray["id"] in PHP - parseJSON["id"]
                        let id = parsedJSON["id"]

                        // successfully uploaded
                        if id != nil {

                            // save user information yang berasal dari server
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(parsedJSON, forKey: "parsedJSON")



                        } else {

                            // get main queue to communicate back to user
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                let message = parsedJSON["message"] as! String
                                self.showAlert(alertTitle: "opppps", alertMessage: message, actionTitle: "OK")
                            })

                        }



                        //  JSON serialization error
                    } catch {

                        // get main queue to communicate back to user
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            let message = error.localizedDescription
                            self.showAlert(alertTitle: "Sorry", alertMessage: message, actionTitle: "OK")
                        })

                    }

                    // error when connecting to server
                } else {

                    // get main queue to communicate back to user
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        let message = error!.localizedDescription
                        self.showAlert(alertTitle: "oppps", alertMessage: message, actionTitle: "OK")
                    })

                }


            })

            }.resume()


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
```

rather than

```
try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```